# Getting different consecutive values on php mockery

Tags: php, mockery, phpunit

**TLDR;**
How do I get `value1` first time and `value2` the second time when calling the mockery `shouldReceive('method`)` with same parameter?

Lets say I have an `$order` object that implements this signature with a method `getState()`.

```
interface Order {
    public function getState();
}
```

Now, on unit tests, I want to use mockery to get mock the `$order` object so that when `getState` is called

- 1st time it returns `initialized` value
- 2nd time it returns `processing` value

Well, I know it could have been done for the case where the return value is different based on parameters using `...->with($param1)->andReturn...`.

Plus `withConsecutive` seems to be the way to do on `phpunit`. How do I implement this on the mockery? I could not found anything about it on [mockery doc](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/) nor on stackoverflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the section [Declaring Return Value Expectations](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html#declaring-return-value-expectations):

> It is possible to set up expectation for multiple return values. By
>   providing a sequence of return values, we tell Mockery what value to
>   return on every subsequent call to the method:
>
> ```
> $mock = \Mockery::mock('MyClass');
> $mock->shouldReceive('name_of_method')
>     ->andReturn($value1, $value2, ...)
> ```
>
> The first call will return $value1 and the second call will return
>   $value2.

Comment: Thank you @Matteo  This is the answer. I must have carefully gone through the doc my bad.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be done using the help of `array_shift` inside mockery's `andReturnUsing` method

```
$orderStates = [
    'intially-order-was' => 'initialized',
    'then-order-becomes' => 'processing'
];

$order
    ->shouldReceive('getState')
    ->andReturnUsing(function() use (&$orderStates) {
        return array_shift($orderStates);
});
```

Comment: Well this works for me but I am not sure if this is the proper way or there is a better way. Please let me know if this is wrong. :)

Comment: Well this my answer was over engineered :) I guess I used extra brain. @Matteo 's answer is the right answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55027266/1818631